# What would "Special Makeup" design have been in the 1988 arcade game, Splatterhouse?

Tags: gaming, software-development, arcade

Upon beating the Namco arcade game *Splatterhouse*, released in November 1988, the following is shown in the credits along with the expected programmers and artists:

[image: Special Makeup credit]

```
 SPECIAL MAKEUP DESIGNED
          AND
       CREATED BY
       DAIHADAN13
```

My mind immediately went to literal makeup on a human actor, but to my knowledge everything in the game and promotional material is too cartoony and exaggerated to have warranted a madeup actor for reference.

I'm curious if "Special Makeup" is a specific programming or game design term in older arcade games.

Comment: This is borderline [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) material, I think.

Comment: @user3840170 Nah, pretty sure they'd pull the "developer intent" card on me. Besides, they're pretty terrible with historical questions. Of course if this isn't a good fit for Retrocomputing, please feel free to close the question

Comment: What is that? (For what it’s worth, I didn’t vote to close. If there are any takers here, maybe it can stay. Or only be migrated afterwards.)

Comment: @user3840170 

Please note, however, that site policies prohibit questions of the following types:

Game and Mod Development (try the Game Development Stack Exchange instead)
Speculations on future of the industry, upcoming (but unreleased) games or content, and **developer intent on mechanics and narrative.**

They wouldn't like asking what Namco meant by makeup, Also, asking about industry verbiage is heavily frowned upon unless it's well-known to the casual player and explicitly game related. I had to fight for a question asking what "ping" was because it wasn't game-related enough.

Comment: This sounds like it was meant for things like ‘which one is the true ending of The Stanley Parable’. So one of them initially well-meaning, but later over-broadly applied and bludgeoned to death close reasons like we see all too often on SO? I think I got it.

Comment: Basically, the reason I'm putting this question on this site is because I was hoping to approach this problem like a programmer in the 80's would have, rather than as a game player. For example, would makeup have been considered shorthand for character model production? Or would it have been industry jargon for customer-facing cabinet design?

Comment: I'm posting this as an answer since I can't prove it, though I'd like to. My -guess- would be that daihadan13 designed some monsters or characters and they were credited in this way as an homage to horror movies. It is -possible- that if the cabinet had a live action photo of a made up character, it could be that too. I believe the chances of it being specific industry jargon for something other than these two are low.

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, I'd say the credit is for contribution to the specific aspects of character design. That said, as much as I am curious to find out the actual answer to this question myself, I'm afraid I don't think it quite fits into the retrocomputing category - this question could just as well be applied to a recently released game.

Comment: @moonwalker Based on that criterion we should not accept anything as on-topic, because any question could just as well be applied to a recently released product.

Comment: @user3840170 and how exactly would you apply to a recently released product a question like "what was the first arcade game to use a microprocessor instead of discrete logic?" My point being, this question is purely about terminology use that's not directly and not even indirectly related to the 1988 technology.